# Data type mismatch in criteria expression exception

Tags: c#, mysql, ms-access

when i run the code it gives me mismatch criteria exception"

[image]

[image]

Comment: change the query to use parameters and you will save yourself a lot of debug headaches as well you are also exposing / setting yourself up for `Sql Injection` do a quick google search on the following 
`C# Stackoverflow OleDbCommand Insert Command.Parameters` tons of awesome working examples out there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the quotes from amounts and category_id

```
"update products set amount=" + amount1 + " where category_id=" + temp;
```

This will build the correct sql string.

BTW I strongly encourage you to use query parameters for your queries https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: why i would remove it? I need the variable to specify which row to be edited

Comment: In sql you use the quotes to delimit strings, amount and category_id are numbers.